# Dictionary values to array according to np.where or similar

Tags: python, numpy

I have a dictionary of integer keys and values:

```
dict1 = {100:1, 101:3, 103:2}
```

I have a numpy array:

```
arr1 = np.array([101, 103, 101, 101, 100, 103])
```

I would like an array of the same length as `arr1` that has the values from the dict that correspond to each entry in `arr1`. That is, I want:

```
arr2 = np.array([3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2])
```

I figure I need to use `np.where` somehow, but I'm blanking.

How can I do this in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr2 = np.vectorize(dict1.get)(arr1)
```

Comment: TypeError: long() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'

Answer (score 2):

you could use a list comprehension and cast to numpy array

```
arr2 = np.array([dict1[x] for x in arr1])
```